# Runtime duration timeout - databricks

Tags: csv, runtime-error, databricks, databricks-community-edition

Databricks environment -
I'm trying to add a tabel(CSV file) in my notebook which is connected successfully to a cluster.

But midway uploading the day an error message is showing which says '*couldn't upload, runtime duration timeout*'

How do I fix this? The CSV file is of 25MB in size.

Comment: can you please add code which are trying for better understand. thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.